# Exclude a result from a matcher

Tags: spacy, spacy-3

I'm trying to specify a pattern that can *exclude* some results.
Given this text: `The Territory for the Titles shall be the United States, its territories and possessions, excluding Puerto Rico`
I am looking for a way to extract only `the United States`, as is a `GPE` and is not excluded.

I tried to write a pattern like `[{'LEMMA': 'exclude', 'OP': '!'}, {'ENT_TYPE': 'GPE', 'OP': '+'}]` that, in my mind, should mean something like "match only if there is anything but the lemma `exclude` followed by one or more `GPE`s.

But in my tests with spacy 3 (and also on the [Rule-based Matcher Explorer](https://explosion.ai/demos/matcher?text=The%20Territory%20for%20the%20Titles%20shall%20be%20the%20United%20States%2C%20its%20territories%20and%20possessions%2C%20excluding%20Puerto%20Rico%20%0A&model=en_core_web_sm&pattern=%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22LEMMA%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22exclude%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22OP%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22!%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22attrs%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22ENT_TYPE%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22GPE%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22OP%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22%2B%22%7D%5D%7D%5D)) the matcher still matches both `be the United States` and `Puerto Rico`.

Is there a way to write a pattern that specifically filter out the `exclude`d `GPE`s?

Comment: looking in github, I found https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2262 that seems to say that there is not a lot of space for a solution

Comment: This is your question on Github https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Puerto Rico` matches because `Puerto` lemma is not `exclude` (obviously).
So a way to filter out `Puerto` is to actually search for something that is not `eclude` nor a `GPE`.

A pattern that works is

```py
[
    {'LEMMA': {'NOT_IN': ['exclude']},
     'ENT_TYPE': {'NOT_IN': ['GPE']}},
    {'ENT_TYPE': 'GPE', 'OP': '+'}
]
```